# gcc g option on compile or build?

Tags: c, debugging, gcc

I know -g option is used for debugging by putting debug symbols on execute file.

I wonder where to put -g option either compile or build may be both.

---

If I have 2 .c files to build ab.out, **where is the correct place to put -g option and why?**

```
gcc (1) -c -o a.o a.c
gcc (2) -c -o b.o b.c
gcc (3) -o ab.out a.o b.o
```

Comment: When you *compile*, otherwise the option would be a *linker* option described in `man ld`... and `man ld` describes it this way *" `-g`  Ignored.  Provided for compatibility with other tools."*

Comment: Thanks for the comment. So it putting -g on all 3 position will do.

Comment: No need with `(3)` you are simply linking object files there. You want `-g` with `(1)` and `(2)` because you are *compiling* (the `-c`) to object files there. You want the additional debug symbols included in the object file. They will be included in the final executable where they are readable by `gdb` for debugging purposes. (they are only usable by `gdb`)  When you use `(3)`  and only provide `.o` (object) files -- they are simply passed along to `ld` for linking. You can do it all at once with `gcc -g a.c b.c -o ab.out` (you should also always include `-Wall -Wextra` for warnings)

Comment: So if I wanted to create a file for debugging with warnings enabled, I would use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -g -o ab.out a.c b.c`. If I wanted to compile with optimizations I would add `-Ofast` (that's 'Oh' not zero) or choose the optimization level `0-3` and use `-O#` where `#` is 0-3 (most optimizations are NOT enabled unless you specify a `-O#` option). A normal non-debug compile with full optimization would be `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Ofast -o ab.out a.c b.c`. You may want to add `-Wshadow` to catch any shadowed variables (e.g. `i` declare in two different scopes). Good luck.